# run time in django views cost time is different in python shell

Tags: django

I am using django and I found a very confusing question. In my views.py like this

```
if request.method == "GET":
    raw_get = request.GET.dict()
    raw_data = ''
    draw = raw_get.get('draw', 0)
    if raw_url == "index":
        recordsTotal = Host.objects.count()
        raw_data = Host.objects.select_related('belongs_to_ostype').prefetch_related(
            'assignedip_set').select_related(
            'belongs_to_PlatForm').prefetch_related(
            'applications__with_vip').prefetch_related(
            'applications__belongs_to_apptype').prefetch_related('applications').all()
        start = time()
        data = {"data": [i.show_index() for i in raw_data], 'draw': draw, 'recordsTotal': recordsTotal,
                'recordsFiltered': recordsTotal}
        end = time()
        print 'cost time', end - start
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

from the terminal, it shows the cost time, like this

```
cost time 10.1911799908
[21/Oct/2016 09:39:54] "GET /assets/data_index/?_=1477013984767 HTTP/1.1" 200 471123
```

Howerver, when I use **python manager.py shell**, I have the follewing

```
def test2():
    recordsTotal = Host.objects.count()
    start = time()
    data = {"data": [i.show_index() for i in raw_data], 'draw': 0, 'recordsTotal': recordsTotal,'recordsFiltered': recordsTotal}
    end = time()
    print 'cost time', end - start
```

This function do the same thing as in views.py,but the cost time is much different. When I run this function, cost time like this

```
>>> test2()
cost time 4.91849398613
```

Why?

Comment: No it doesn't do the same. In the first function you do prefetch like 4 times and then add .all() for some reason. Of course it runs slower.

Comment: No, in **python manager.py shell** , I have defined the **raw_data** inside the test2 function, the **raw_data** is the same as in views. Plus the fact the **select_related** and ** prefetch_related** does't actually trigger sql, it won't cost time

Comment: You running through raw data in the first function — that hits the DB. In the second, if you define it manually, it obviously doesn't hit the DB. Basically you're testing two different things here.

Comment: @Andrey Shipilov, I'v rewrited the **test2** function, and added raw_data inside the test2 function,it's true that the **raw_data** cost some time, the result is about 7s, I'v tried 4 times. But it's still not equal to the time cost in views

Comment: `test2()` will fail because `raw_data` is not defined in it